# VB.net txt text file merge / concatenate all files

Tags: vb.net, text-files, concatenation

I have combined all logfiles by using the following code and shelling to dos.

```
    pi2.Arguments = "/c for /r c:\logs " + "%F in (*.*) do @type " + """%F """ + ">>c:\logs\Master"
    pi2.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    p2.StartInfo = pi2
    p2.Start()
    p2.WaitForExit()
```

This put all the information in one file but for some reason changes the format.  If i do a simple copy *.* *.txt in dos it merges them all and its readable but when i do the above code it changes the format.  Any ideas?

Comment: Changes the format how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies it was a rookie error the text reader was corrupt i have just re installed it.  Sorry if i have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings in VB, you need to use the `&` operator.

```
pi2.Arguments = "/c for /r c:\logs " & "%F in (*.*) do @type " & """%F """ & ">>c:\logs\Master"
```